# How to deal with union type that has undefined in it?

Tags: typescript, types, undefined, nestjs

I have this function that used to return `UserResponseDto | undefined`. Now I want to refactor it so I will be returning `UserResponseDto | NotFoundDto`. The function `this.userService.findOne()` is returning `Promise<User | undefined>`.

Currently I have this:

```
async findOne (@Param() params): Promise<UserResponseDto | undefined> {
  return this.userService.findOne(params.id)
}
```

I want something like this:

```
async findOne (@Param() params): Promise<UserResponseDto | NotFoundResponseDto> {
  const user = await this.userService.findOne(params.id)
  if (typeof user === "undefined") {
    return new NotFoundResponseDto()
  }

  return new UserResponseDto(user) // 1
}
```

But unfortunately I can't seem to get rid of that `undefined` in `User | undefined` part. In `// 1` the `user` is still treated as `User | undefined`. Should I use `user as User`? I feel like it's a nasty workaround though.

Am I missing something? Can it be done easier without a ton of boilerplate code?

---

`UserResponseDto` is a class that takes 1 argument in the constructor `user: User` and extends `SingleResponse<User>`.

---

This is another function I'm using that is very similar to this one:

```
async update (@Param() params, @Body() dto: UpdateUserRequestDto): Promise<User | undefined> {
  const user = await this.userService.update(params.id, dto)
  if (typeof user === 'undefined') {
    return undefined
  }

  return this.userService.findOne(user.id) // 2
}
```

Here I have not gotten around to changing `User` to `UserResponseDto` yet and in `// 2` VS Code is seeing user as `User`. Not as `User | undefined` which is exactly what I want from the first function.

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using? This should work correctly in the latest version.

Comment: `2.6.1` inside VSCode.

Comment: By the way, this isn't an improvement of your code, you only make it more complex without achieving anything. It would be if you would look at functional programming - things like monads, where you return one and the same container structure and in it there may be a value or not, but your code does not care, no "ifs" to check if there is a value, you can just chain the operations regardless. Now instead of for `undefined` you check for something else instead - no net gain. There isn't even any additional information in that `NotFoundResponseDto` thingy. Might as well keep the `undefined`.

Comment: I need the `NotFoundResponseDto` because this is the way to structure response. The decorators in that class are used by Swagger to generate documentation for API (Nest framework).

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your problem.  I tested on the latest typescript. What is the definition of `this.userService.findOne` ?

Comment: The function `this.userService.findOne()` is returning `Promise<User | undefined>`.

Comment: I tried the code with the strictNullChecks option enabled. It works fine for me. Could you post a full sample that reproduces your problem ?   Also make sure that the compiler is actually 2.6.1.

Comment: Instead of doing `NotFoundResponseDto` you could throw `NotFoundException` in `UserService` and than catch that exception with [Exception Filter](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters). That way your code will be much cleaner - you only take care of working logic in controller.

Answer (score 0):

userService.getOne is likely your issue. Here are some common problems:

1. If getOne() throws an error, and it is uncaught, findOne will return undefined.
2. If getOne() possibly returns undefined, findOne could possibly return undefined.

Basically, check the userService.getOne() to see it's return type (possibly explicitly declare it), then you should be good to go.